# Arduino Uno R3 L(yellow) led stays on and error on upload

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide

So I recently got an Arduino Uno R3. Installed the IDE and drivers under Windows 8.1 and everything seemed to work fine and received the 'Done uploading' message when goofing around with the Blink example(was in a hurry that day).

Next day when I connected the Uno, I noticed the L(yellow) led keeps staying on and I get the following error when trying to upload:

```
System wide configuration file is "/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/home/cy/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

         Using Port                    : /dev/ttyS0
         Using Programmer              : arduino
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20]
```

I tried on both Windows and Ubuntu and am really excited about learning things with Arduino. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you got it working *at all* using Ubuntu, or was the goofing just in Windows? Each time you reboot your PC (at least for me) I have to select the correct COM port in the IDE from Tools -> Port. I think the same goes for my Linux setup (debian based), but I use that for a slightly different programming process, and I've never received an upload error using linux so I don't know what they look like. Could you add the error you get from Windows too? The current error message suggests that the IDE can't find your board.

Comment: The goofing around was only in Windows. I plugged the board now and I got "USB Device not recognised".